# Why <?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?> still output /wp-content/themes/twentynineteen?

Tags: theme-development, themes, templates, child-theme

I've developed some twentynineteen-child template. Today, I need to convert [my last child-template](https://oripeau.com/) into a *template stand-alone*.

I removed the following line from the style.css file:

```
Template: twentynineteen
```

And added a few lines to my functions.php file:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'oripeau_setup' ) ) :
function oripeau_setup() {
    load_theme_textdomain( 'oripeau', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary'   => __( 'Primary Menu', 'oripeau' ),
        'secondary' => __('Secondary Menu', 'oripeau' )
    ) );
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array ( 'aside', 'gallery', 'quote', 'image', 'video' ) );
}
endif;
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'oripeau_setup' );
```

I renamed the template folder:

```
wp-content/themes/oripeau
```

But *echo get_template_directory_uri()* still output

```
/wp-content/themes/twentynineteen
```

**Question:** what am I forgetting?

Comment: You need to deactivate and reactivate your theme.

Comment: Brilliant!
It's working.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to deactivate and reactivate your theme.

When a theme is activated the `template` and `stylesheet` values are set in the database. If you remove `Template:` from the child theme's stylesheet, the `template` is still set to `twentynineteen` in the database, so `get_template_directory_uri()` will return its URL. Re-activating the theme will ensure that this isn't set to the wrong theme anymore.

Comment: Brilliant!
It's working.
Thank you so much.


PS. I wanted to vote for your answer, but as I am a new user of the forum, my vote is not considered. If someone reads these lines lost somewhere on the internet, vote for that answer. :D